# What does "as much the......as......" mean?

Tags: grammar, structure

"We are as much the universe as a neutron star."

What does "as much the universe as a neutron star" mean in this sentence? Can you explain the structure used here?

Comment: Question is unclear

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Provide the context and source of the sentence. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The full context (which you should have given) is that this is a quote from a video about 'Optimistic Nihilism', which seems to be a kind of modern philosophy.

> “We are as much the universe as a neutron star, or a black hole, or a
> nebula. Even better, actually, we are its thinking and feeling part,
> the sensory organs of the universe.”

We can use expressions like

*something* is **as much** *something* **as** *something else [is]*

to assert that the first thing is fully equal in some way to the second thing, often to contradict, or forestall, an idea that the first thing is not fully the equal in status to the second thing.

I am as much a citizen as you are!

Rice is as much food as meat is.

My dog is as much deserving of life as the King.

The video seems to be saying that 'we' (human beings) are equally important parts of the universe as astronomical objects such as neutron stars, etc.

Whether this is a trivial or profound observation is, I would suggest, a matter of opinion.